# Create Ticket using Freshdesk api, response is always { "logout": "success" }

Tags: jquery, json, logout, freshdesk

Well, I have tried every thing mentioned in Freshdesk api (**http://freshdesk.com/api#create_ticket**) to create new ticket but with no success,

Here is what I am doing in RESTClient to create ticket:

Mehtod: POST
URL:https://milliontech.freshdesk.com/helpdesk/tickets.json

Headers:
Content-type:application/json
Authorization:(Basic Authorization using APIKEY:X)

Request Body:

```
{
  "helpdesk_ticket":{
      "description":"I am not able to create this ticket... bla bla bla",
      "subject":"Urgenta",
      "email":"toma@outerworlda.com",
      "priority":1,
      "status":2
  },
  "cc_emails":"rama@freshdeska.com,diana@freshdeska.com"
}
```

And this is the response:

```
{
    "logout": "success"
}
```

I have also tried with curl command to create new ticket but ended up in the similar result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid this response

```
{
    "logout": "success"
}
```

and create ticket successfully

Just clear your browser's cache every time you create new ticket (If you are using RESTClient in Mozilla or Chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps others in the future, had issues with the logout success message even after clearing cache, also started getting an internal 500 error, but after consulting Freshdesk support this code worked for me:

```js
(function($){ 
  var settings = { 
    "async": true, 
    "crossDomain": true, 
    "url": "https://company.freshdesk.com/helpdesk/tickets.json", 
    "type": "POST", 
    "headers": { "authorization": "BasicAuthKey", "Content-Type": "application/json" }, 
    "data": "{\r\n \"helpdesk_ticket\":{\r\n \"description\":\"Some details on the issue ...\",\r\n \"subject\":\"Support needed..\",\r\n \"email\":\"tom@outerspace.com\",\r\n \"priority\":1,\r\n \"status\":2\r\n },\r\n \"cc_emails\":\"youremail@gmail.com\"\r\n}" 
  } 
  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) { 
    console.log(response); 
  });
}(jQuery))
```

So it seems the data value needs to be stringed in that way, I had to modify the code later to work with a form but this worked great for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any restclient browser add on? Or is there any script that you are using?
I am from Freshdesk and just tried to analyzing this issue and everything looked fine and was able to create a ticket using API on your account.

Please try out the below curl command and let me know if the issue still persists.
Just replace the APIKEY with your API Key from Profile Settings.

```
curl -u APIKEY:X -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "helpdesk_ticket": { "description": "I am not able to create this ticket... bla bla bla", "subject": "Urgenta", "email": "toma@outerworlda.com", "priority": 1, "status": 2 }, "cc_emails": "rama@freshdeska.com,diana@freshdeska.com" }' -X POST https://milliontech.freshdesk.com/helpdesk/tickets.json
```

Comment: Thanks ArjunA for your answer, but it was not helpful because I have already mentioned in my question that I had already tested curl command to create ticket, and yes of-course using my own APIKEY and my own company URL and with https as the prefix

Comment: I just spent an hour trying to resolve this same issue before I found this thread! To confirm, clearing the cache worked. I was using the Advanced Rest Client Chrome add on. The browser seemed to be adding the 'Cookie' header to the request which was resulting in the `logout: success` response. Removing this header from the request resulted in a ticket being successfully created.